# parsed soapobject failed to show in listview

Tags: android, web-services, android-listview, android-ksoap2

I wrote a simple webservice using JAVA to search data from database and return an `ArrayList<String>`. In my Android client application, I use Soap. And I plan to show the result in a ListView. When debugging as an Android Application, the results show in the ListView. When I just run it as an Android Application, the results fail to show in the ListView.

Here is my webservice code and some of my Android application code.

My Android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://nuaaagetest";
    private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.105:8080/nuaaagetest/services/test?wsdl";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getCourselist";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
    private ListView courselist;
    private ArrayList<String> clist = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        accountInfo = getSharedPreferences("accoutInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        courselist = new ListView(this);
        courselist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,clist));
        setContentView(courselist);
    }

    private class showTestasynctast extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... Urls) {
            showtestws();
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    };


    private void showtestws() {
        String user = accountInfo.getString("account", null);
        testws(user);
    }

    public void testws(String user) {

        try {
            SoapObject testsp = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            testsp.addProperty("userid",user );
            HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.bodyOut = testsp;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(testsp);
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            clist = parseCourse(result);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private ArrayList<String> parseCourse (SoapObject obj)throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<obj.getPropertyCount(); i++){
            String str = obj.getProperty(i).toString();
            list.add(str);
        }
        return list;

    }
}
```

My webservice code:

```
package nuaaagetest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;




public class test {
    public ArrayList<String> getCourselist(String userid) {
        ArrayList<String> courselist = new ArrayList<String>();
        ResultSet rs;
        String str;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nuaage","root","131209");
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select cnm_sc from SCourse where sid_sc = '"+ userid +"'");
            while(rs.next()){
                str = rs.getString("cnm_sc");
                courselist.add(str);
            }

        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return courselist;
    }

}
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: you are doing `clist = parseCourse(result);` but where are you using it? could you check `size` of the `clist` after above statement and see if you have actually obtained any data?